How to assume an AWS role from a pull request job? What sub value should be used?
I'm using github actions, and I need to assume an AWS role from a job triggered by a pull request event. I'm using the configure-aws-credentials action, and my OIDC provider and AWS roles are already created. I'm actually already able to assume this role from jobs triggered on a branch workflow, as I set up the role's trust policy as such:
"Condition": {
    "StringEquals": {
        "token.actions.githubusercontent.com:aud": "sts.amazonaws.com"
    },
    "StringLike": {
        "token.actions.githubusercontent.com:sub": "repo:<myorg>/<myrepo>:ref:refs/*"
    }
}

But PR jobs fail to assume the role. What value should be used for sub for PR jobs to assume the AWS role?

To assume an AWS role from a job triggered by a PR event, set up the role to accept the following value as sub:
repo:ORG-NAME/REPO-NAME:pull_request

Source

You can configure a subject that filters for the pull_request event. In this example, the workflow run must have been triggered by a pull_request event in a repository named octo-repo that is owned by the octo-org organization:


Syntax: repo:ORG-NAME/REPO-NAME:pull_request


Example: repo:octo-org/octo-repo:pull_request

Example in the trust policy:
"Condition": {
    "StringEquals": {
        "token.actions.githubusercontent.com:aud": "sts.amazonaws.com"
        "token.actions.githubusercontent.com:sub": "repo:<myorg>/<myrepo>:pull_request"
    },
}

